# Sort with inconsistent equals and compareTo method Java

Tags: java, equals, comparable

I have a POJO say Animal.java which looks as under:

```
class Animal{   
  String name;
  String owner;
  String color; 
}
```

Two animals are equal if they have same name and ownwer. So, I need to override equals and hashcode accordingly:

```
   @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + name.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + owner.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Animal other = (Animal) obj;
        if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (!owner.equals(other.owner))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Now the problem is that whenever I display an ArrayList on Animal , I want to display it sorted based on `color` field.
If I use Comparable and override compareTo as follows:

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Animal o) {
        return color.compareTo(o.color);
    }
```

Then my equals and compareTo methods are inconsistent. This is also a problem.

So, how do i sort my ArrayList of `Animal` based on `Animal.color`?

Comment: Don't implement `Comparable`, create a custom `Comparator` instead. Refer to the linked question.

Comment: Okay yes that seems correct:
    class AnimalNameComparator implements Comparator<Animal>{
    public int compare(Animal o1, Animal o2) {
    return o1.getColor().compareTo(o2.getColor());
    }
    }